# Two boxes, identical other than mass and density, are pushed with a coefficient of kinetic friction $\mu$. Do they slow down at the same rate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

Do they slow down at the same rate? And stop simultaneously?

I believe they do because $v_f = v_0 -\mu g t$ for both. But I'm not completely sure why that is.

I've also seen another equation for the slow down due to friction.

$x=\frac{v_o}{\mu}(1-e^{-\mu t})$

I've been told both are correct.

Neither equation involves mass.

Comment: apply the second law and see that both have the same acceleration

Comment: Doesn't $\mu$ grow if the mass of the box grows?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I don't believe so because u=[friction force]/[force normal] so they do slow down  at the same rate, i am nearly certain. but I am unsure of if the first formula actually makes sense. the second formula actually follows from the definition of friction force.

Comment: $v_f = v_0 -\mu g t$ I explained why this doesn’t make sense in response to your previous question.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes. But two other people suggested it is correct without the $m$ ($\mu$ is dimensionless so the whole thing seems to work out dimensionally, as someone else told me.) But you also noted that it would go to -infinity as time goes to 0. But I was thinking maybe you could ignore that and say it stops at 0.

Comment: “*$\mu$ is dimensionless*” $\mu$ is clearly *not* dimensionless in the second formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two $\mu$s are of different origin. The second $\mu$ depends on the mass.

The first equation
$$ \tag{1}
v_f = v_0 - \mu g t.
$$

The is kinetic friction
$$
   f_k = \mu N = \mu m g;\\
   a = f_k / m = \mu g.
$$
The accelaration is independent of mass.

But the second equation:
$$ \tag{2}
x=\frac{v_o}{\mu}(1-e^{-\mu t})
$$

This was from the damping force $f_d = -\gamma v$ with damping coefficient $\gamma$

The corresponding equation of motion
$$
  m \frac{dv}{dt} = - \gamma v;\\
   \frac{dv}{dt} = -\frac{\gamma}{m} v \equiv - \mu v.
$$

The velocity
$$
  v(t) = v_0 e^{-\mu t}.
$$

This integrates again $x(t) = \int v(t') dt' $ to get the position of Eq.(2). The $\mu = \gamma / m$ in equation 2 is mass dependent, and of diiferent nature from that in Eq.(1).